# Read twitter user_timeline.xml?screen_name="xyz" file content in csharp

Tags: c#, twitter

any can tell me the procedure (code ) to retrieve the ID and Message(text Tag) value in c# variable from the http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name="xyx";
URL in c#.

Answer (score 1):

You could use code like this:

```
var url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=" + name;
var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var statuses = from status in doc.Root.Elements("status")
               select new
               {
                   Id = status.Element("id").Value,
                   Text = status.Element("text").Value
               };
```

Comment: If you want to display the first status, you could do something like: `var first = statuses.First(); MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: {1}", first.Id, first.Text));`.

Answer (score 0):

[Link to Twitter is definitely an option.](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/)

Their code example:

```
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext();

            var publicTweets =
                from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                where tweet.Type == StatusType.Public
                select tweet;

            publicTweets.ToList().ForEach(
                tweet => Console.WriteLine(
                    "User Name: {0}, Tweet: {1}",
                    tweet.User.Name,
                    tweet.Text));
```

That said, i'm a big fan of Linq syntax.